# Making Ctrl+C copy text in gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, clipboard

Is it possible for me to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> perform a copy command *if there is highlighted text* in the terminal?
Otherwise, it should retain its normal behavior.

(If there is a terminal that can do this other than gnome-terminal, that's probably fine too.)

Comment: You don't have to use the mouse; on a Mac keyboard you can use `shift`+`enter`+`fn`. And, on a 'normal' keyboard, I think it's `shift` and `insert`.

Comment: I confirm. I just use another blend of copy-fu on a 'normal' keyboard: Ctrl+Insert for copy (and Shift+Insert for paste) which does not conflict with program interrupt Ctrl+C

Comment: Just wanted to say that I want exactly the behavior you want (Ctrl+C behaves differently when something is selected). I hope one day there's an answer to your actual question!

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can change the keybinding for Cut and Paste from the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to what you say, namely <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, in the *Edit → Keyboard Shortcuts* menu. Though you should also change the default terminal meaning associated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (interrupt), for example in this way

```
stty intr ^J
```

(I chose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> because I don't remember it is associate with some action, but you can make your own choice.)

I don't think it is possible to retain the default interrupt action for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> only when there is no text highlighted.

Comment: As noted by @Pithikos in the answer of mangoDrunk , after remapping the Copy shortcut to Ctrl+C, you can use Ctrl+Shift+C to interrupt without having to configure anything else.

Comment: I set it to ^Q bacause it's normally "unfreeze/start" which is rarely used, harmful and is closer to CTRL. If someone decides to do this as well, they mustn't forget to remap "start" first like: stty start ^J

Comment: Note that it is impossible to set it to a combination involving Shift using `stty`. (I've set it to ^X, as 'cutting' makes no sense here.)

Comment: I don't how this exactly implemented it. But in idea in the terminal, you could use Ctrl+C as copy and as interrupt depending on the context.

Comment: I don't see an "edit" button in terminal... How do I get it?

Comment: is it possible to make those changes directly in the text file rather than through the clicks in the GUI?

Answer (score 44):

As already noted, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> is typically used for interrupting a program. But instead of using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy, which I do much more frequently than interrupting a process, I change the setting to have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to interrupt.

You can do this in GNOME Terminal by going to "Edit" -> "Keyboard Shortcuts..." and map the "Copy" action to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and "Paste" to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>. The interrupt command will automatically be remapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: But how do I then map Ctrl+Shift+C to interrupting a process?

Comment: It happened automatically for me. All I did was set Copy to Ctrl+C and after saving that, Ctrl+Shift+C became interrupt.

Comment: @mangoDrunk the reason is that holding `Shift + Ctrl + <key>` essentially prints the same character as  `Ctrl + <key>`. You can test with `read`

Comment: I suggest doing this because I copy paste a LOT more than I interrupt a process and it's easy to remember ctrl+shift+C as interrupt rather than change my habit of copy which is the same everywhere else.

Answer (score 43):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> is already assigned to another command, which is the one that interrupts the program that is running in the terminal 
For example, ping www.google.com will start pinging Google until you tell it to stop. The way you do it, is by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

So, they couldn't just change the assignment of that combination.

Highlight the text you want to copy, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and it is copied to the clipboard. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> and you paste it.

Let me know if it doesn't work...

Comment: Rather than saying that those keybindings have other specific meanings in the terminal, it is probably more correct to say that various console applications expect to be able to use them, so if the terminal emulator didn't pass them on it might make those apps unusable.

Comment: OS X is a bit smarter: when some text is selected it interprets `Ctrl+C` as copy and when no text is selected it interprets it as interrupt.

Comment: Actually, OS X is not smarter. The copy keyboard shortcut is  Cmd-C, not Ctrl-C.

Answer (score 35):

Apart from what @Dan said, there's another option for copy-pasting text in Linux, which I'm finding much faster and easier to use, since there's no need to switch from mouse (which you're using to make the selection) to keyboard:

- selecting text with mouse copies it to clipboard
- <kbd>middle-click</kbd> pastes it.

This feature is especially useful in terminal, for example when assembling a command from bits of text which are already on screen.

This works in all applications, so it's possible to copy-paste text from a web page to terminal etc.

The clipboard buffer used for <kbd>middle-click</kbd> copy-paste is separate from the one used for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, which makes it possible to have two different bits of text copied at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

To make cut and paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) work in the console or terminal, put the following code into terminal to change the key bindings automatically:

```
gconftool-2 -t str -s /apps/gnome-terminal/keybindings/copy "<Control>c"

gconftool-2 -t str -s /apps/gnome-terminal/keybindings/paste "<Control>v"
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for writing an answer on this, it looks like I spent too much of my reputation on a bounty for being able to post a comment.

There is no way to change the behavior of keyboard shortcuts depending on whether there is a text selection or not, and I would avoid reassigning the terminal's Ctrl-C.

BUT, you can easily get accustomed to

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> for copying
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> for pasting

This works practically everywhere (except in [Nautilus](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=584709), sigh), and hardly ever interfers with anything!

Comment: +1. I use these wherever I can because easier to reach without moving the fingers much.

Answer (score 3):

Is someone wanted you could use:

```
> stty intr ^K         # free Ctrl+C for copy use Ctrl+K instead
> stty lnext ^-        # free Ctrl+V for paste use ^- instead
> stty -g
> stty -g > ~/.stty    # store the settings in home directory
```

Add the following to `~/.bashrc`

```
case $- in
 *i*)
   stty `cat ~/.stty`     #  reload the stored stty settings
   bind -u quoted-insert  #  unbind the quoted-insert function of bash - free Ctrl+V for paste
esac
```

And then gconf editor or somesuch to change terminals keybindings to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for Copy and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for paste.

Comment: Argh...the formatting got skrewed up. See: http://sandipchitale.blogspot.com/2008/10/reclaim-ctrlc-and-ctrlv-for-familiar.html

Comment: In my option, that's a stty way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

in [Lxterminal](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXTerminal) (default terminal in Lxde ), you can fully customize shortcuts:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> won't work because of the interrupt usage, but I just figured out a way that worked for me. My goal was to have to press only two keys, not three, and preferably something I'm used to, and not in a too inconvenient place on the keyboard.

The keyboard I have on my Linux box has a "Windows" key, in the same place as the "Command" key on a Mac. So I just went to *Edit* → *Keyboard Shortcuts* and I changed the shortcuts to use this key, so it now says <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. I sometimes use a Mac too, so this was easy to get used to.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you cannot because in gnome terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> do not work.
For cutting, copying and pasting you have to highlight the text, right click and choose the action you want to do

Comment: you still can you use short cuts to cut in the terminal these are ctrl+shift+c (copy) and ctrl+shift+v (paste) and ctrl+shift+x.

Answer (score 0):

On terminator you can change the bindings by doing the following:

- <kbd>right-click</kbd> on the terminal screen. Select *Preferences*.
- Go to *Keybindings*.
- <kbd>double-click</kbd> on the command set for *Copy* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> by default) and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on keyboard.
- The *Copy* command is changed. Repeat for the *Paste* command.
- Exit *Preferences*.

Now you can use normal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to copy and paste respectively.

Comment: It is not a good idea to just bind `Ctrl + C` like that and not have a solution of retaining the initial "Interrupt behaviour" of the command somehow. A lot of commands and scripts expect an interrupt command to be terminated. For example, a countinous `ping`, `tail -f`, etc.