# Is there a terminal that behaves like a console from web browsers?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making Ctrl+C copy text in gnome-terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53688/making-ctrlc-copy-text-in-gnome-terminal)

Is there such a terminal where I can edit the text like in usual text area, i.e.

Copy - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, paste - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and so on?

Good example is console in Chrome or in Firefox.

Then I don't need to remember all these shortcut keys.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any.  However, you can change the shortcuts manually:
`Terminal > Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts`

Then set Copy to `Ctrl + C`, and `Ctrl + V` for paste.

P.S. how do you get those "keys" to show up? [Where they look like buttons, as opposed to text]

Answer (score 0):

Most shells use keyboard shortcuts like ctrl+c for other things, so if you use it top copy text, then that will break basic functionality, which is why gnome-terminal uses ctrl+shift+c, for instance.