# Why don't Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V work in a terminal?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making Ctrl+C copy text in gnome-terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53688/making-ctrlc-copy-text-in-gnome-terminal)

`Ctrl+C` an `Ctrl+V` work well under my Ubuntu except in a terminal:

If I want to past something into a terminal, I need to right click mouse and choose `paste`; if I want to copy something from a terminal, I need to right click mouse and choose `copy`...

Does anyone know how to enable `Ctrl+C` an `Ctrl+V` in Terminal?

Thank you very much

Comment: See this question too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/53688/making-ctrlc-copy-text-in-gnome-terminal