# Copying code directly into the console with keyboard shortcuts

Tags: console, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making Ctrl+C copy text in gnome-terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53688/making-ctrlc-copy-text-in-gnome-terminal)

I am have installed Ubuntu 10.04 right now, and I am getting quite a bit of code examples from my browser, Firefox, where the usual `ctrl-c` short cut works but it doesn't seem to work for pasting the code directly, `ctrl-v`, into the shell console.

This isn't a critical issue,pasting with the mouse still works,but any suggestions as to how to activate `ctrl-v` or what the correct native short-cut for the console is would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `gnome-terminal` you have to user <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> to paste and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to copy.