# How to make an interrupt assignment in the terminal stick

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, clipboard

I followed the instructions from enzotib's answer on [Making Ctrl+C copy text in gnome-terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53688) to make the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> keys act consistent in the terminal and then re-assign <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> to be the cancel/interrupt key for ongoing processes.

The instructions works great...until I close the terminal. Next time I open the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> has to be re-assigned. I don't want to have to type out

```
stty intr ^J
```

each time I open terminal. How do I make that key assignment stick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are concerned only with terminals opened from the desktop (e.g. *gnome-terminal* ), just add `stty intr ^J` to your `.bashrc`.

- Run this command *once* in a terminal:

  ```
  echo stty intr ^J \ >> ~/.bashrc
  ```
- Close that terminal; the assignment should now stick in every gnome-terminal you open