# Use Ctrl + C and Ctrl + V for Copy and Paste

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

Right now, I have Copy and Paste bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> in the Ubuntu terminal. However, that is not ideal. I would like Copy and Paste to work like in any other application, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.
Q1: When I bind Copy to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, how can I then kill processes?
Q2: Would it be possible to bind kill processes to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> ?

Comment: This might be helpful [change bash shortcut keys such as Ctrl-C?](https://superuser.com/questions/160388/change-bash-shortcut-keys-such-as-ctrl-c)

Comment: and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114392/copy-paste-in-a-terminal-without-shift and https://askubuntu.com/questions/53688/making-ctrlc-copy-text-in-gnome-terminal

Comment: @Rinzwind  and singrium Thank you! I was able to rebind it thanks to the links you provided.

Comment: Then I shall close it as a dupe :D